# Swift compiler error: segmentation fault: 11 on Archive

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, enums, segmentation-fault

When archiving my iOS app prior to submission for App Store release, I get an error that says

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Then there's a huge block of paths and whatnot and at the end is a mention of a function that I have in the app. Here's the function:

```
func matrixOperationRequiresScalar(operation: MatrixOperation) -> Bool {
    switch operation {
    case .Addition, .Subtraction, .Multiplication, .Division, .Negative, .Determinant, .Inverse, .Transpose, .EigenOps: return false
    case .ScalarMultiplication, .ScalarDivision, .Power: return true
    }
}
```

You can tell that `operation` is an enum and all cases are covered here.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: there is no default case in your switch and those are required

Comment: Well, what do ya know? That fixed it. Thank, you. Feel free to leave this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switch you have in your code is missing the default case which is required in swfit. You can easily correct this :

```
func matrixOperationRequiresScalar(operation: MatrixOperation) -> Bool {
    switch operation {
    case .Addition, .Subtraction, .Multiplication, .Division, .Negative, .Determinant, .Inverse, .Transpose, .EigenOps: return false
    case .ScalarMultiplication, .ScalarDivision, .Power: return true
    default: return true
    }
}
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html)